# Objects generated by javascript vanish right after appearing

Tags: javascript, python

On a button click I'm calling a python script and I'm populating the result into an array. Once done, I create `<a href>` as many `<a href>` objects as the length of the array. Problem is, once the links are displayed, they vanish immediately.

```
Body:
//I obviously get the same effect by putting the onclick event in the submit button
window.onload = function() {
    alert("loaded");
    document.getElementById('submit_searchsubs').onclick = function () { 
        FindSubtitles();
    };
};

function FindSubtitles() {

        postData = {"movie": "Outlander", "season":"1", "episode":"2"};             
            $.ajax({
                url: "/cgi-bin/find_subtitles.py",
                type: "post",
                datatype:"json",
                async : false,
                data: {postData},
                success: function(response){
                    var subs = new Array();
                    var json = $.parseJSON(response);
                    for (var i=0;i<json.length;++i) {
                        subs[i] = new Array(json[i].IDSubtitle, json[i].SeriesEpisode, json[i].SubHash, json[i].SubDownloadsCnt, json[i].SeriesSeason, json[i].ZipDownloadLink, json[i].MovieName, json[i].id, json[i].SubFileName);
                    }
                    DisplaySubtitles(subs); //show the users the new words found in this subtitle
                } 
            })
            .fail(function(err) {
                alert("error" + err);
            });

    }

function DisplaySubtitles(subs) {
        var SubtitleDiv = document.getElementById("SubtitleDiv");
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        for (i = 0; i < subs.length; i++) {
            var linkText = document.createTextNode(subs[i][8]);
            a.appendChild(linkText);
            SubtitleDiv.appendChild(a);
        }
}
```

So what happens:

1. Page loads
2. alert("loaded") is displayed as it's fired in window.onload
3. FindSubtitles runs
4. DisplaySubtitles runs and `<a>` links appear
5. `<a>` links disappear and alert("loaded") is displayed again.

I don't know if I should use `async: true`, because in that case I get `[Object object]` error, which is strange because in case of another script I use that, otherwise it would freeze the UI.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your 'submit_searchsubs' a form button that submits? Maybe the page is reloading after a form submit.

Comment: That was it. It was an input button and it reloaded the page. I changed it to a traditional button and now it works! Thanks! Pls add this as an answer.

Comment: I choose, instead, to give you imaginary points!  Glad I could help.

Comment: @erdomester If by "traditional button" you mean a <button> element, how does that solve the problem? Neither `<input type="button">` nor `<button type="button">` performs a submit. By the way, please note that if you don't supply a `type` attribute to the button element, some browsers will, under some circumstances, submit the page too. So it's best to always provide the `type` you want explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

As Kieveli mentioned, if submit_searchsubs is a form button that submits, it may be refreshing the page after submit.  Try using return false; to bypass the default browser onclick action.

```
document.getElementById('submit_searchsubs').onclick = function () { 
    FindSubtitles();
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Nice - wasn't sure on how to bypass.